# On commas and conjunctions + of course

Tags: conjunctions, punctuation

Grammatically speaking, should there be a comma before "of course" when it's preceded by a conjunction?

Examples:

> He ordered a batch of cup noodles and other instant food. And(,) of
>   course, beer.
>
> They tried fighting that losing battle, but(,) of course, they failed
>   in the end.

Why or why not? (Maybe there should be a comma because "of course" is a parenthetical phrase?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Grammatically speaking, should there be a comma before "of course" when it's preceded by a conjunction?

*"First, let me say that, while punctuation and grammar are related, details like commas don't generally make something ungrammatical."* - [JavaLatte (Grammar, punctuation, comma)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/171516/grammar-punctuation-comma/171518#171518)

The commas may change how the sentences are read, but they do not affect the grammaticality of your sentences.

> (Maybe there should be a comma because "of course" is a parenthetical phrase?)

Whether something is parenthetical (i.e., nonessential information) or not depends on the author (i.e., what the author wants to convey).

> He ordered a batch of cup noodles and other instant food. And(,) of course, beer.

Note that you either put both commas (to set off "of course" as a parenthetical element **in the middle** of a sentence) or you don't put any at all ***if* you don't intend to set it off as a parenthetical element.**

The single comma does not make much sense (to me); it is not required because the sentence is quite small.

There are three reasons to put a single comma: (1) To indicate a pause in speech, (2) to emphasize or draw attention to "beer", and (3) to indicate that "And of course" is an introductory phrase (as pointed out in comments by userr2684291).

I personally would not use a single comma to indicate that "And of course" is an introductory phrase, given how small (one word - beer) the rest of the sentence is. If I were to use a single comma, it would be either for (1) or (2).

Yes, if you want to indicate a strong break in thought, use the pair of commas to set off "of course" as a parenthetical element in the middle of the sentence. If you find yourself emphasizing "of course" when you are reading out the sentence (i.e., if you are changing the tone a bit), then you are actually looking to create some sort of an effect with "of course". If this is true, use the pair of commas. This will indicate the break in your thought or the change in your tone.

If your tone is relatively unchanged and smooth, and if none of the three reasons above for a single comma applies to you, then "of course" is just filler material, and you don't need commas. If at least one of them applies, then use a single comma.

Comment: The single comma looks fine to me, and you'll find style manuals recommending it. [Here](https://www.stltoday.com/travel/travels-with-amy/south-bend-indiana-city-offers-art-museums-adventure-and-of/article_4cd88b7d-7bf2-5b3a-9b3c-edb698466405.html)'s one example of such usage. Flanking commas are customary in this situation, however. I would regard *And of course beer.* as somewhat unsightly, and would prefer *And of course – beer.* or the alternatives mentioned in the question. An alternative way to punctuate the second sentence would be *[...] battle but, of course, they failed [...]*.

Comment: @userr2684291 I did mention in my answer that the single comma may be fine when it is meant to indicate a pause in speech, or when we want to emphasize and draw attention to "beer". If, however, "of course" is to be set off as a parenthetical (nonessential/nonrestrictive), it requires two commas. In your linked example, *South Bend: Indiana city offers art, museums, adventure and, of course, Notre Dame*, "of course" is a parenthetical element (it is set off by two commas). Also note how the oxford comma is not used before "and".

Comment: For the OP's second example, your suggestion "... battle but, of course, they failed ..." uses "of course" as parenthetical. You have just omitted (or not used) the comma for the coordinating conjunction. But that is not relevant to the question. I would use "... battle, but, of course, they failed ..." because when you remove the parenthetical it becomes "... battle but they failed ..." which is an independent clause joined by a coordinating conjunction, and it requires a comma before "but": "... battle, but they failed ...".

Comment: 1. It doesn't have to draw attention to *beer*; it can instead be used to set off an introductory phrase (*of course*). 2. It doesn't require two commas, as I said. 3. I didn't even see that sentence – the one I'm referring to is *And of course, there’s the Fighting Irish.*. Lighter punctuation favors omitting all unnecessary commas (the Oxford one in the cited example is kinda implied there – *...adventure, and, of course, Notre...* would be conventional but punctuation-heavy). 4. Omitting the comma before *but* there is fine, and that's relevant as it makes the double commas more acceptable.

Comment: *And of course, **there’s the Fighting Irish** ... * is a very different sentence than the one where there is just one word after the introductory phrase - "beer". But, sure, it does work like that as well - for setting off introductory phrases. "Introductory phrase" is something the OP does not talk about, however. And a parenthetical **in the middle of a sentence** does require two commas. I clearly said that OP should use two commas **if** they want "of course" to be parenthetical element. Omitting the comma before "but" is *not* relevant here because the OP doesn't ask about it (cont.)

Comment: @userr2684291 The OP only asked about commas for the purposes of parenthetical elements. So far, I don't really see what you are trying to point out. Are you saying something I wrote in my answer is incorrect? If so, what is it? Can you please quote it. Also, if the answer is not useful, please feel free to downvote. And feel free to post whatever you think is the right answer. I did mention the single comma can be used for a pause or to draw attention. It can also be used to set off introductory phrases (which is not what OP asked about, but if it makes the answer any better I will add it).

Comment: @userr2684291 Again, as I see it you have a different opinion about using the comma before the coordinating conjunction "but" in the second example. That is fine. But why are you telling me this? Does my answer say anything about it?

Comment: That sentence isn't at all different from the sentences at issue. The reason why I wrote what I wrote about the single comma is "The single comma does not make much sense (to me) [...]", i.e. it makes sense to me. And "introductory phrase" normally refers to a phrase starting a clause, not necessarily an entire sentence. The second example features two clauses: the *but* one could have its own introductory phrase. Again, omitting the comma before the *but* makes flanking the *of course* look more acceptable when using a lighter punctuation style, regardless of what the asker is focusing on.

Comment: Further, "Note that you either put both commas (to set off 'of course' as parenthetical) or you don't put any at all." is why I commented – the issue isn't necessarily as black-and-white as you describe it. And "If your tone is relatively unchanged and smooth, then 'of course' is just filler material, and you don't need the commas." is also why I commented. I think this very much depends on style, which is why I said what I preferred. The way you said it sounds like they don't have to include the commas if the tone is "smooth", but my personal style mandates some kind of punctuation there.

Comment: @userr2684291 This needs to be moved to chat. Have a look at the edit to my answer. If you have a different preference, and if you disagree with what I said, then why don't you write a separate answer instead of trying to force me to agree with you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108051/discussion-between-aiq-and-userr2684291).

Answer (score 1):

This dictionary
[Collins "of course"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of-course)

calls it an adverb, and shows examples of its use not set off by commas.
 I think commas, or even parentheses, could be used, if you wanted to frame it that way, but it's not necessary.